# Modify the command to go back in stack in vim

Tags: vim

I want to modify the command that is used to go back in tag stack in Vim from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>

I edited `~/.vimrc`

```vim
noremap <C-_> <C-T>
```

But it is not working, I am using Vim in freebsd and the tag file was generated using exctags.

Comment: Why do you map `_` instead of `I`?

Comment: Ah, I believe the formatting is very unlucky here. You want to map Ctrl-Minus, right? The "I" starts the next sentence. You can use backticks or  <kbd> tags. But svaslov's question remains: if you want `-`, why do you map `_`?

Comment: @Friedrich
Yes I needed Ctrl - (minus)
But - and _ are on the same key but it is not working

Comment: Well, 'A' and 'a' are on the same key but they're different characters. What you did will work if you press Ctrl+Shift+Minus. I tried `<C-->` but that changed size of my terminal in Vim and still did nothing in gVim. Some keys just cannot be mapped, I don't know if that's one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ctrl+Something combos that can theoretically be mapped in Vim are the ASCII control codes in [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#Basic_ASCII_control_codes). Of note:

- Some combos may be intercepted by your system, your terminal emulator, etc. thereby reducing the number of mappable combos.
- There is no `^-` in that table so you can't map it.

If your environment satisfies its requirements, the new-ish `:help modifyOtherKeys` might help but it is not very portable.